# How to determine row equality across several rows in a fully vectorized way?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, similarity

I have a `numpy.ndarray` called `grouping` of size `(S, N)`. Each row of `grouping` gives me the group labels of a sample of data. I run my algorithm `S` times and get new group labels in each iteration.

I want to determine how many times each sample of my data has the same group label as every other sample of my data across the `S` iterations in a fully vectorized way.

In a not-completely-vectorized way:

```
sim_matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
for s in range(S):
    sim_matrix += np.equal.outer(grouping[s, :], grouping[s, :])
```

Comment: a sample of your data always helps.

Comment: What are typical values of `S` and `N`?

Comment: @Divakar S is about 5,000 and N is in the 10s of thousdands

Comment: do you really need the full sim_matrix? or is it a derived quantity thereof that is of actual interest? And what is the typical sparsity (percentage of nonzeros) from a single call to np.equal.outer?

Comment: @hoogendoorn I do need the full sim_matrix but would be happy with the percents, i.e. sim_matrix/S. It's somewhat sparse, ~20% True in np.equal.outer.

Comment: In that case, and for the S/N numbers you mentioned, I think this loopy solution is pretty much optimal

Answer (score 2):

One vectorized approach would be with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(grouping[:,None,:] == grouping[:,:,None]).sum(0)
```

For performance, we can use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) -

```
np.count_nonzero(grouping[:,None,:] == grouping[:,:,None],axis=0)
```

Comment: This works! But it's totally consuming my memory where the for loop wasn't. I upvoted.

Comment: @NewNameStat Yeah, that's the trade-off here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare identic rows. A way to do that is grouping the entire rows in a raw block :

```
S,N=12,2
a=np.random.randint(0,3,(S,N)) #12 samples of two labels.

#a
    0  1
0   2  2
1   2  0
2   1  2
3   0  0
4   0  1
5   1  1
6   0  1
7   0  1
8   0  1
9   0  0
10  2  2
11  0  0

samples=np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(dtype((void,a.strides[0])))
```

`sample.shape` is then (S,1).

you can now  inventory your sample with `np.unique`, and use Pandas dataframes for pretty report :

```
_,inds,invs=np.unique(samples,return_index=True, return_inverse=True)

df=pd.DataFrame(invs)
result=df.reset_index().groupby(0).index.apply(list).to_frame()
result['sample']=[list(x) for x in a[inds]]
```

for

```
          index samples
0                      
0    [3, 9, 11]  [0, 0]
1  [4, 6, 7, 8]  [0, 1]
2           [5]  [1, 1]
3           [2]  [1, 2]
4           [1]  [2, 0]
5       [0, 10]  [2, 2]
```

It can be  a O(S ln S)  if there is few fits between samples, when yours is O( N²S).

Answer (score 0):

The sum of `equal.outer` is a cryptic way of calculating all-pairs similarity of columns:

```
sum_i sum_jk (A[i,j] == A[i,k])  is the same as
sum_jk sum_i (A[i,j] == A[i,k])
```

where `sum_i` loops over rows, `sum_jk` over all pairs of columns.
Comparing two vectors by counting the the number of positions where they differ
is called
[Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) .
If we change `==` above to `!=`, similarity to distance = nrows - similarity
(most similar ⇔ distance 0), we get the problem:
find the Hamming distance between all pairs of a bunch of vectors:.

```
def allpairs_hamming( A, dtype=np.uint32 ):
    """ -> Hamming distances between all pairs of rows of A """
    nrow, ncol = A.shape
    allpair_dist = np.zeros( [nrow, nrow], dtype=dtype )
    for j in xrange(nrow):
        for k in xrange( j + 1, nrow ):
            allpair_dist[j,k] = allpair_dist[k,j] = (A[j] != A[k]).sum()  # row diff
    return allpair_dist

allpairs_hamming: 30.7 sec, 3 ns per cmp  Nvec 2000  Veclen 5000  A 10m  pairdist uint32 15m
```

Almost all the cpu time is in the row diff, not in the outer loop `for j ... for k` -- 3 ns per scalar compare, on a stock mac, isn't bad.
However memory caching is much faster if each row `A[j]` is in contiguous memory,
as for numpy C-order arrays.
Apart from that, whether you do "all pairs of rows" or "all pairs of columns"
doesn't matter, as long as you're clear.

(Is it possible to find "nearby" pairs in time and space < O(npairs), here O(20000^2) ? Afaik there are more methods than test cases.)

See also:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html (bug: hamming .mean not .sum)
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html
https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[clustering]+pairwise